# Function interruption

Tags: php, security

I can't find any material on "function interruption" vulnerabilities that seem to plague older versions of PHP.  Anyone have a good source on the matter?  A good source being something that describes the attack/why certain php functions were vulnerable?

Comment: Just curious: If only old versions of PHP are affected, why you don't just update, instead if juggling around with problems, that should never occur?

Comment: It was an interest.  I have newest version of php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 seconds of Googling: http://www.php-security.org/MOPB/MOPB-37-2007.html and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=619324

Comment: I have no idea why my eyes scanned over that link.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

It's very old, in late 2007. But here you have one link I found after a minute of searching ... Google is your friend!
http://www.php-security.org/MOPB/MOPB-37-2007.html